# Bypass iFrame buster script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to bypass iFrame detection (ie buster) scripts.

I'm able to bypass this detection:

```
if (top !== self) {
   //break out
}
```

with injecting this code on top:

```
window.self = window.top;
```

But what if I have something like this:

```
if (window != top) {
   //break out
}
```

How can I redefine `window` ?

Comment: First: bypassing the frame-buster may violate the terms of use, and you may be sued for that. Then: `window` is the global Object, it references the DOM, all available Libraries in JS, ... everything; don't mess with that/don't break that. As an idea: you could change the condition on the JS-file before it is evaluated. wich probably would also violate the terms of use, and if you don't do a really good job at this, you might have created a more unpleasent experience for your customers, than the iframe. namely: sometimes it works, sometimes not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't redefine the `window` and `top` properties of the global object**

`window` is essentially a reference to the `window` property of the global window object (`window.window`). This property is defined as non-configurable and non-rewritable. You can verify this by executing `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "window")` in the console. The `configurable: false` and `writable: false` attributes mean that any attempts to modify it will fail (either with a `false` return value or with an error in strict mode). This behavior of the `window` property is required by the [specification of the Window object](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object).

The `top` property of a window is non-configurable and non-rewritable as well, so you won't be able to overwrite that either. (`parent` and `self`, on the other hand, can be overwritten.)

You seem to be trying to find a universaly usable way of fooling framebusters. This seems like an impossible task to me. You might be able to somehow intercept `<script>` elements and remove the iframe detection from the code before it gets executed, but even if you succeed in doing so for some framebusters, there will always be other ones that your extension will not take care of.